# Creating a sparse Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I am working on graphing and working with signals from a system before and after an event which happens at t=0.  Below you can see a table that contains the count of 2 message codes(A,B) at 4 different times in hours. The time range I am working with is 1-30 hours after the event, and a 1-30 hours before the event(my negative hours).When I pad all missing hour with 0s for each error code the execution time is very slow. However I still need to graph the values with 0's to see how the data changes over time. Also when I pad the dataframe, all positive time has a response of 0, and negative time has a response of1.

All of this data for multiple error codes resides in a pandas dataframe, and I am attempting to pad all of the missing 0s in a sparse manner. But the big problem is execution time is incredibly slow, and I want to find a faster more efficient solution.

```
import pandas as pd

my_data = {}

my_data['Time(Hours)'] = [8,26,-12,-26]
my_data['Msg_code'] = ['A','A','B','B']
my_data['Msg_code_count'] = [1,2,1,1]
my_data['System'] = ['Sys4','Sys4','Sys4','Sys4']
my_data['Response'] = [1,1,0,0]

pd.DataFrame(my_data)
```

[image: My Dataframe]

At the end of the day, how can I create a dataframe that stores my missing zeros in a sparse manner, like scipy.sparse.coo_matrix?

Thanks again!

Comment: why you are not using scipy.sparse.coo_matrix ?

Comment: I am not sure yet on how to keep all values zeros for all error codes that have missing data. And to also keep the response variable accurate. Maybe I should try this approacch